# не удается получить доступ к папке в которой находиться проект, ошибка UnauthorizedAccessException при вызове при вызове File.CreateText()

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, файлы

```
if (passed)
{
    DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
   
    using (StreamWriter streamWriter = 
        File.CreateText(directoryInfo.FullName)) // выдает ошибку System.UnauthorizedAccessException нет доступа по указанному пути
    {
        streamWriter.WriteLine($"Balance cash ={BalanceCash.ToString()}");
        streamWriter.WriteLine($"Balance card ={BalanceCard.ToString()}");
    }
    
    MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
    mainWindow.Show();
    this.Close();
}
```

Я хочу создать текстовый файл в папке проекта и записать в него  строки, как мне получить права чтобы это сделать?или есть какой то другой способ создать файл? При попытке создать текстовый файл и записать в него что-то меня выдает ошибку `UnauthorizedAccessException` при вызове `File.CreateText()`. Пробовал сделать папке общий доступ средствами Windows 10, но тщетно.

Comment: `directoryInfo.FullName` это что, имя текущей рабочей папки? Вы пытаетесь файл создать с каким именем конкретно?

Comment: это путь куда нужно создать. А вообще то да я не указал имя файла, но у метода CreateText не было аргумента на  имя файла.

Comment: Единственный аргумент это и есть путь до файла, включая имя файла. [path String The file to be opened for writing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.createtext?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: мда... я реально забыл про имя файла я думал что он сам сгенерирует, но я не понимал почему ошибка  типа UnauthorizedAccess, а не ArgumentException, спасибо.

Comment: а как пометить вопрос решенным?

Comment: Скинул ответом, просто отметьте его галочкой (слева от ответа) и все дела.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

directoryInfo.FullName это что, имя текущей рабочей папки. Вам вместо папки надо передать путь к файлу, включая имя файла.